# Does ASP.NET Core's policy-based authorization require specific claim types in the token?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm thinking about switching from role-based to [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in my ASP.NET Core API.

I am currently using JWT to handle authorization, with the current user's role added to the access token as a `ClaimTypes.Role`. My guess is that the default `[Authorize]` attribute uses the `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()` method to authorize requests, which in turn looks specifically at claims where the claim type equals `ClaimTypes.Role`.

Now if I switch over to policy-based authorization, I need to replace roles with permissions inside my access tokens. The question is, am I okay to continue adding those permissions to my token as `ClaimTypes.Role`, or should I be using a different `ClaimTypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to modify the ClaimTypes.Role , you could continue using it.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.infrastructure.rolesauthorizationrequirement?view=aspnetcore-6.0) description, I suggest you could use policy based authorization will also check the role claim.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole(""));
});
```